# Azure Search search.in() filter not working

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have an Azure Search index with a filterable field called aReportNumber (an int). From the portal index fields:
"aReportNumber Edm.Int32 Filterable, Retrievable"

I'm using API version 2016-09-01-Preview via Microsoft.Azure.Search 4.0.1-preview - I checked the API version in the debugger:

ApiVersion = "2016-09-01-Preview"
UserAgent = {FxVersion/4.6.00001.0 Microsoft.Azure.Search.SearchIndexClient/4.0.1.0}

When I set my filter as: "search.in(aReportNumber,'291, 409')" I get:

Invalid expression: No function signature for the function with name 'search.in' matches the specified arguments. The function signatures considered are: search.in(Edm.String, Edm.String, Edm.String); search.in(Edm.String, Edm.String)

Both exist in the index and can be found with the filter "aReportNumber eq 291 or aReportNumber eq 409".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, `search.in` function is supported on string fields (fields of type `Edm.String`) only.

Comment: Thanks Eugene. No reason it has to be an int anyway - its not like i'm going to do calc on an id number, and we have int.TryParse if we really need it :-).

Comment: Additional: you might want to tell Heidi that. It wasn't clear from the doc (or I'm hard of understanding)